# SQLAlchemy - Getting a list of tables

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I couldn't find any information about this in the documentation, but how can I get a list of tables created in SQLAlchemy?

I used the class method to create the tables.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

All of the tables are collected in the `tables` attribute of the SQLAlchemy MetaData object.  To get a list of the names of those tables:

```
>>> metadata.tables.keys()
['posts', 'comments', 'users']
```

If you're using the declarative extension, then you probably aren't managing the metadata yourself.  Fortunately, the metadata is still present on the baseclass,

```
>>> Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
>>> Base.metadata
MetaData(None)
```

If you are trying to figure out what tables are present in your database, even among the ones you haven't even told SQLAlchemy about yet, then you can use table reflection.  SQLAlchemy will then inspect the database and update the metadata with all of the missing tables.

```
>>> metadata.reflect(engine)
```

For Postgres, if you have multiple schemas, you'll need to loop thru all the schemas in the engine:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inspector = inspect(engine)
schemas = inspector.get_schema_names()

for schema in schemas:
    print("schema: %s" % schema)
    for table_name in inspector.get_table_names(schema=schema):
        for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name, schema=schema):
            print("Column: %s" % column)
```

Comment: Deprecated since version 0.8: Please use the sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect() method. And notice, use `engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql://user:password@host/db_name')` rather than `"mysql://user:password@host"` and `engine.execute("use db_name")`.

Comment: @XuJiawan: I'm not sure which thing is deprecated here, I'm not sure which method im suggesting if it's not `sqlalchemy.MetaData.reflect()`?

Comment: @IfLoop: I found it from [the sqlalchemy document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.params.reflect).

Comment: @XuJiawan: The link suggests that the `reflect` *argument* to `MetaData.__init__`, a boolean flag, is deprecated *in favor* of using `MetaData.reflect()`, exactly as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: @IfLoop: Very sorry about my poor English. Your answer is exactly right and I've upped it. I added that comment just to let people notice that if they use version<0.8, they may not use `MetaData.reflect()` method in this way. And also comment it for someone else who may have the same problem caused by the engine declaration.

Comment: `metadata.tables.keys()`, what is `metadata` ? Where's it imported from?

Comment: It's a attribute on my Base object.

Comment: The only correct answer!

Answer (score 105):

There is a method in `engine` object to fetch the list of tables name. `engine.table_names()`

Comment: i get
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dedup_jobs.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(engine.table_names())
  File "/Users/darshanchoudhary/.virtualenvs/services/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2128, in table_names
    return self.dialect.get_table_names(conn, schema)
    value = value.replace(self.escape_quote, self.escape_to_quote)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`
(stack truncated)

Comment: This works also with *Flask-SQLAlchemy*, since there is [direct access to the engine](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.engine) via e.g. `DB.engine.table_names()` or whatever the name of the database variable is.

Comment: this is deprecated and you now must use 
```
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine(self.__connection_string)
        insp = inspect(engine)
        return insp.get_table_names()
```

Answer (score 67):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://use:pass@localhost/DBname')
print (engine.table_names())
```

Comment: This is the correct answer that works as of November 2018.

Comment: If it doesn't work then it's most likely because the engine can't connect correctly (so a problem in line 2) but you won't get the error message until you run `engine.table_names()`

Comment: Use this answer people.

Comment: this is deprecated and you must use 

```
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine(self.__connection_string)
        insp = inspect(engine)
        return insp.get_table_names()

```

Answer (score 47):

- To get a list of all existing tables in DB:

As of SQLAlchemy 1.4: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#fine-grained-reflection-with-inspector

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import inspect
engine = create_engine('...')
insp = inspect(engine)
print(insp.get_table_names())
```

Older methods (`engine.table_names()`) yield:

`SADeprecationWarning: The from_engine() method on Inspector is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please use the sqlalchemy.inspect() function on an Engine or Connection in order to acquire an Inspector. (deprecated since: 1.4)`

- To get a list of declared tables, use accepted answer: `metadata.tables.keys()`

Comment: In the case of using sqlite follow the instructions: from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import inspect
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///your_path_name/data_base_name.db')
insp = inspect(engine)
tables = insp.get_table_names()
print(tables)

Comment: If you have multiple databases/schemas, make sure to include the schema= parameter in the call to get_table_names. Otherwise, you get the names from the 'default' schema. (at least that's what I'm finding in MySQL 8)

Comment: @ben It is impossible to have multiple databases in an RDBMS. We can only have one database and within that database we will have many schemas that define the relationship of tables with eachother.

What you usually run into in online posts or even in documentations of RDBMSs! and described as "multiple databases" is fabricated term due to lack of academic knowledge.

It is crucial to use these terms and words properly. Obviously, SQLAlchemy is also trying hard to stick to the correct terms: 1 database->multiple schemas (schemata).

Comment: @Ash I get your point, and you are technically correct. I just mention multiple databases because MySQL uses the terms database and schema interchangeably. I'm not sure if any other DBs do, but it's confused me more than once.

Answer (score 14):

Within the python interpreter use db.engine.table_names()

```
$ python
>>> from myapp import db
>>> db.engine.table_names()
```

Comment: Note: This does not work for SQLAlchemy 2.0

Comment: as James say, you must switch to Inspector, as per docs

```
        from sqlalchemy import create_engine
        engine = create_engine(self.__connection_string)
        insp = inspect(engine)
        return insp.get_table_names()

```

Answer (score 11):

I was looking for something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
eng = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:password@localhost:3306', pool_recycle=3600)
q = eng.execute('SHOW TABLES')

available_tables = q.fetchall()
```

It does an execute and returns all of the tables.

**update:**

Postgres:

```
eng = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://root:password@localhost/
q = eng.execute('SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_tables')
```

Comment: This is not cross-platform. It will only work with mysql, it will not work with other database engines.

Comment: @EdwardBetts you are right, what db engine were you wondering about?

Comment: OP asked for postgres not sql

Comment: @oelhajoui Either the question is edited or the OP didn't ask for Postgres. Either way there is no point in using SQLAlchemy if your code is not corss-platform.

Comment: SQLAlchemy has plenty of uses for non-cross-platform code. For instance, you can use it to assemble queries dynamically without having to put together raw SQL strings in your code (which results in an unreadable mess for a query of any complexity).

Answer (score 9):

I personally do this and it works:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inspector = inspect(engine)
inspector.get_table_names()
```

It gives me all the names in my db.

Comment: `engine` is undefined.

Comment: I defined engine like this : 

`from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///CryptolIVE.DB')`

Answer (score 7):

The metadata object that you created the tables with has that in a dictionary.

```
metadata.tables.keys()
```

Comment: Make sure to execute `metadata.reflect(bind=engine)` before this.

Answer (score 7):

I'm solving same problem and found this post. After some try run, I would suggest use below to list all tables: (mentioned by zerocog)

```
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
for table in metadata.sorted_tables:
    print(table)
```

This is useful for direct table handling and I feel is recommended.

And use below code to get table names:

```
for table_name in engine.table_names():
    print(table_name)
```

"metadata.tables" provides a Dict for table name and Table object. which would also be useful for quick query.

Comment: this! without the ```reflect```, ```metadata.sorted_tables``` won't work

Answer (score 7):

Just this simple:

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect

inspect(engine).get_tables_names()

# engine.table_names()  # Deprecated after 1.4
```

Also, to test whether a table exists:

```py
engine.has_table(table_name)
```

Comment: will be deprecated...

Comment: Deprecated, see here for fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76629428/848419

Answer (score 4):

The best way is to use `inspect`:

1. Create the inspector and connect it to the engine
2. Collect the names of tables within the database
3. Collect Table columns names

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///../Resources/dow.sqlite")
conn = engine.connect()
inspector = inspect(conn)
inspector.get_table_names() #returns "dow"

columns = inspector.get_columns('dow')

for column in columns:
    print(column["name"], column["type"])
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what I'm using as of 2021-10-22:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sql

engine = sql.create_engine("connection_string")

sql.inspect(engine).get_table_names()
```

Answer (score 4):

I use a *List Comprehension* to extract table names, it works for me

```
# Import necessary module
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

# Create engine: engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database.sqlite')

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)

table_names = [table.name for table in metadata.tables.values()]

print(table_names)
```

Answer (score 3):

Reflecting All Tables at Once allows you to retrieve hidden table names too. I created some temporary tables and they showed up with

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=myengine)
for table in reversed(meta.sorted_tables):
    print table
```

Reference http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can get them from your db instance

```py
[...]
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.engine.table_names() # you'll get a list of all the table names in your database
```

Comment: Give me a `AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'table_names'`

Comment: I think an answer to your comment is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76629428/4887136

Comment: Thanks. "The engine.table_names() function is deprecated since version 1.4" so no longer a viable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Complete example of displaying all column information. Assumes variable `df` contains a dataframe to be written to the SQL database.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy_utils.functions import database_exists, create_database

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydb.sqlite', echo=True)

if not database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)
else:
    engine.connect()

df.to_sql('MyTable', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False) # index=False avoids auto-creation of level_0 (name tiebreaker)

inspector = inspect(engine)
table_names = inspector.get_table_names()
for table_name in table_names:
    print(f"Table:{table_name}")
    column_items = inspector.get_columns(table_name)
    print('\t'.join(n for n in column_items[0]))
    for c in column_items:
        assert len(c) == len(column_items[0])
        print('\t'.join(str(c[n]) for n in c))
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner:

```
sqlalchemy.inspect(my_connection.engine).get_table_names()
```

Where:

```
my_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"{dialect}+{driver}://{login}:{password}@{host}/{db_name}")

my_connection = my_engine.connect().execution_options(schema_translate_map={None: schema})
```