# I get the following error running sqlalchemy in replit: AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'table_names'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, replit

I'm using replit. and in the console, I ran the following command:

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

Then, in the main.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///census_nyc.sqlite')
connection = engine.connect()
print(engine.table_names())
```

the error I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(engine.table_names())
AttributeError: 'Engine' object has no attribute 'table_names'
```

I'm trying to follow datacamp's introduction to relational databases and I've fallen at the first hurdle.

I tried the above code exactly as presented in the training videos but it doesn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473925/sqlalchemy-getting-a-list-of-tables if you want to list tables. See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#basic-usage for the sqlalchemy documentation and introduction. If you want commentary on a specific tutorial you are following then link to it; I seems the `table_names` method was removed several versions ago.

Answer (score 1):

The `engine.table_names()` function is deprecated since version 1.4:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.table_names

You can use the `inspect()` function for runtime information on any SQLAlchemy objects, including the engine. This creates an inspection object which can be queried for more information.

For your need:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///census_nyc.sqlite')
inspection = inspect(engine)
inspection.get_tables_names()
```

More info on the inspection API:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/inspection.html#sqlalchemy.inspect